# SQL Server 2019 ProgrammingError: Incorrect syntax near 'AUTO_INCREMENT'

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment, create-table

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting this error and how to solve it.

The code:

```
CREATE TABLE sqlalchemy_generic_types 
(
    'No.' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'Object Name' VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    'Description' VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY('No.')
);
```

The error:

> (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'AUTO_INCREMENT'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
> [SQL: /* Creating a table */
> CREATE TABLE sqlalchemy_generic_types (
> 'No.' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
> 'Object Name' VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
> 'Description' VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY('No.')
> );]
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)

Comment: It's `AUTO INCREMENT` and not `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support auto-increment.  Nor does SQL Server -- or any other database -- support single quotes for column names (as far as I know).

I would recommend writing the statement as:

```
CREATE TABLE sqlalchemy_generic_types (
    sqlalchemy_generic_type_id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ObjectName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

Note the changes:

- `IDENTITY()` is assigns an increasing value to the id.
- The `id` is given a meaningful name.
- The space is removed from `ObjectName`, so the name does not need to be escaped.
- No escape characters are needed to define the table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the `double quotes` for column names if they contain special characters or spaces.

`Auto_increment`? -- you must be looking for `identity(1,1)`

You can use following query:

```
CREATE TABLE sqlalchemy_generic_types (
    "No." INT NOT NULL identity(1,1),
    "Object Name" VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    "Description" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("No.")
);
```

[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=34fc4db839d723de24102e84f542a45d)